# pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: distribute error on new Plone 4.3 instance

Tags: plone

I've just installed a new plone 4.3 instance in a folder which already contained 2 Plone 4.3 instance, which both work fine. When I try to run buildout I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/buildout", line 17, in <module>
    import zc.buildout.buildout
  File "/usr/local/Plone4.3/buildout-cache/eggs/zc.buildout-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 40, in <module>
    import zc.buildout.download
  File "/usr/local/Plone4.3/buildout-cache/eggs/zc.buildout-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/zc/buildout/download.py", line 20, in <module>
    from zc.buildout.easy_install import realpath
  File "/usr/local/Plone4.3/buildout-cache/eggs/zc.buildout-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/zc/buildout/easy_install.py", line 31, in <module>
    import setuptools.package_index
  File "/usr/local/Plone4.3/Python-2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.35-py2.7.egg/setuptools/package_index.py", line 158, in <module>
    sys.version[:3], require('distribute')[0].version
  File "/usr/local/Plone4.3/buildout-cache/eggs/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 666, in require
    continue    # try the next older version of project
  File "/usr/local/Plone4.3/buildout-cache/eggs/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 565, in resolve

pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: distribute
```

Google has failed me. Can anyone tell me how to resolve this error?

Comment: Looks like the `distribute` installation is broken; you have both `distribute` and `setuptools` installed (one in the `site-packages` folder and one in the `buildout-cache/eggs` directory.

Comment: One or the other is redundant; I suspect running `Python-2.7/bin/python bootstrap.py` should clear this as it is the `bin/buildout` script that is broken here.

Comment: I have already run bootstrap but it made no difference

Comment: Can you delete the `buildout-cache/eggs/setuptools-*.egg` directory and try again?

Comment: You can do the same to `/usr/local/Plone4.3/Python-2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.35-py2.7.egg`; `bootstrap.py` will download the right package. The problems are all due to `distribute` being a fork of the `setuptools` project; the two projects later on were merged again, but your `bootstrap.py` would need to be updated to take advantage of that.

Comment: I've just tried reinstalling the whole instance, and now it's functioning correctly. I guess it was probably something I did directly after creating the old instance.

Comment: Well, somehow your setup ended up with both `setuptools` and `distribute` (one an egg explicitly drawn in by buildout from the egg cache, the other installed in your `site-packages` directory (so 'globally' for the interpreter). And they conflicted.

Comment: For others in this situation, bootstrapping with the --distribute flag may cure the problem.